# PHP Echo foreach from XML

Tags: php, foreach, echo

I am reading an xml file with:

```
<imageref>image1.jpg|image2.jpg|image3.jpg|image4.jpg</imageref>
<hotelname>villa test</hotelname>


foreach ($filtered as $hotel) {     
    $xmlhotels[] = array(        
        'image'=>(string)$hotel->imageref,
        'villaname'=>(string)$hotel->hotelname
    );
}
```

When I echo the villaname foreach value I get it.

```
foreach ($myhotels as $villa) {    
echo"",$villa['villaname'],""; }
```

How can I echo just the first image (image1.jpg) from the xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [explode()](http://php.net/explode) and do something like this:

```
foreach ($filtered as $hotel) {     
    $xmlhotels[] = array(        
        'image'=>explode('|', $hotel->imageref),
        'villaname'=>(string)$hotel->hotelname
    );
}

foreach ($myhotels as $villa) {    
    echo $villa['villaname'];
    echo $villa['image'][0];
}
```